# Display particle emitter in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

Trying to use SKScene to display a particle emitter spritekit file in a View.

Current code

```
struct ContentView: View {
 
    var scene: SKScene {
            let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "magicSparkles")!
            scene.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
            scene.scaleMode = .fill
            return scene
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .padding()
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
                       .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
                       .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to do this the simulator throws an error.

```
Moodie2 WatchKit Extension crashed due to an uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException. Reason: -[SKEmitterNode setScaleMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003e981c0.
```

Comment: "magicSparkles" is a particle emitter, not an SKScene. The exception is thrown when you are trying to pass an emitter as a scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things:

1. SpriteKit content does not display in the Xcode preview, only in simulator app or on device, fyi!
2. You just have to go ahead and add the particle to a SpriteKit scene and place that in your view, instead of just an emitter.

Code (ignore the flower shape):

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct flowerhshape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
                let width = rect.size.width
                let height = rect.size.height
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.66071*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.19416*width, y: 0.83929*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.75929*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.08698*width, y: 0.83929*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.30444*width, y: 0.80786*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.23532*width, y: 0.83929*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.2726*width, y: 0.82786*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.82143*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.49704*width, y: height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.92*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.38987*width, y: height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.82143*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.60422*width, y: height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.92*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.68965*width, y: 0.80786*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.79993*width, y: 0.83929*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.72071*width, y: 0.82786*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.75876*width, y: 0.83929*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.99409*width, y: 0.66071*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.9071*width, y: 0.83929*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.99409*width, y: 0.75929*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.88302*width, y: 0.5*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.99409*width, y: 0.58929*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.94826*width, y: 0.52857*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.99409*width, y: 0.33929*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.94826*width, y: 0.47143*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.99409*width, y: 0.41071*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.79993*width, y: 0.16071*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.99409*width, y: 0.24071*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.9071*width, y: 0.16071*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.68965*width, y: 0.19214*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.75876*width, y: 0.16071*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.72149*width, y: 0.17214*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.17857*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.49704*width, y: 0), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.08*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.60422*width, y: 0))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.17857*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.38987*width, y: 0), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.08*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.30444*width, y: 0.19214*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.19416*width, y: 0.16071*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.27337*width, y: 0.17214*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.23532*width, y: 0.16071*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.33929*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.08698*width, y: 0.16071*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.24071*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.11106*width, y: 0.5*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.41071*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.04582*width, y: 0.47143*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.66071*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.04582*width, y: 0.52857*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.58929*height))
                path.closeSubpath()
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.5*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.49704*width, y: 0.32143*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.40143*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.60422*width, y: 0.32143*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.5*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.38987*width, y: 0.32143*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.40143*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.49704*width, y: 0.67857*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.30288*width, y: 0.59857*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.38987*width, y: 0.67857*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.5*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.60422*width, y: 0.67857*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.6912*width, y: 0.59857*height))
                path.closeSubpath()
                return path
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
            
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
            SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .top)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
//            .withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever())
            .clipShape(flowerhshape())
           
            Text("Honor thy error as a hidden intention")
                .font(.caption2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .frame(alignment: .top)
                
        }
        .padding(.top, 12.0)
        .frame(alignment: .bottom)

    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of using SKScene(fileNamed: "magicSparkles"), replace the SKScene with SKEmitterNode. Not sure if the rest of the code will run correctly though

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer to this question, although it has an issue that I have been unable to solve on the watch. I have used Spritekit with SwiftUI on an iOS device, but never on watchOS. The first thing I learned is that `func didMove()` does not exist on watchOS, so you have to use `func sceneDidLoad()` to implement things. The following code will put an emitter on the watch:

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var scene = EmitterScene()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
       SpriteView(scene: scene)

         
        }
    }
}

class EmitterScene: SKScene {
    
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        if let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "magicSparkles"){
            emitter.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
            emitter.zPosition = -1
            addChild(emitter)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having with it is that the emitter particles do not appear correctly. They are overly large and you have to futz with the emitter to make it dense enough that they regularly show, but they seem to be scaled up to almost the same size as the watch face itself. I have no idea how to resolve that.

Comment: ah the app runs, but the simulator screen is still black... I think i'm messing something else up

Comment: hey so 1) i didnt know spritekit stuff doesnt show in xcode preview, only in simulator lol

Comment: 2) I ended up placing the particles in a scene and then using the scene (you have to add a refernece node as a parent to the particles) instead and the scaling thing was solved

Comment: Please put it up as an answer if you can. I want to see the code.